# Using USB5742 USB 3.2 Gen 1 HFC IC with pre-configured firmware

Tags: pcb, usb, microchip, usb-device, usb-hub

Due to Chip Shortage problem, I have been looking for USB 2.0 Hub Controller for long time now.

I need only two USB 2.0 Downstream (PHY) ports for my design.
I contacted MicroChip and they have the suggested: [USB5742](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/USB5742-Data-Sheet-DS00002016F.pdf) Hub Feature Controller IC with 2 USB 3.2 Gen 1/USB 2.0 downstream ports.

[here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4stv045b2ce1uw/AN1903-Config-Options-for-USB5734-USB5744-USB5742.pdf?dl=0) are Config Options for USB5742.

I'm using USB2.0 Upstream port from Alder Lake CPU as described in [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x3wuv6x912pqcxw/SBC-APL_2.pdf?dl=0) PDF (the HUB will be added to the Extension Board).

the problem is that Microchip said the stock they have for USB5742 has the following configuration option installed on it's FW:

• bcdUSB 9200,   => USB Specification Number which device complies too.

• HFC is turned off always, => HFC stands for Hub Feature Controller, you can find more information about it in the attached APP note.

• Port 2 is configured as NonRem => NonRem for non-removable port.

How can I make sure I can order this chip and I won't have any functionality problems? I didn't get enough information regarding these features, and I wonder if there is something that could interfere with my application. as shown in the block diagram, the USB 2.0 downstream ports will be used for WWAN and WIFI/BT M.2 Modules.
Note: I have the original FW of the device but I'm not interested in providing a header\hardware solution to manually re-install it.

As I understood, bcdUSB field indicates the version of the USB specification to which the device conforms. For example, 0x0200 indicates that the device is designed as per the USB 2.0 specification. 
Unfortunately, I didn't get what 9200 means in this case because there is no USB 9.2 specification.

I'm contacting Microchip through a supplier, and I didn't get a clear answer from them regarding this subject. they just provided me with the features that are pre-configured on the chip and a zip file with the original firmware. their response time is too slow and I need to make a decision regarding buying or not buying this stock before it's gone.